# Convert const uint16 arr[] to uint16 arr[]

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How to convert

```
const uint16 arr[]
```

to

```
uint16 arr[]
```

using c++ ? Please post an example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to keep the variable name same or is it ok to change it? Do you want the memory to be constant?

Comment: @Manoj: you can change variable name and memory need not be constant...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not bothered about variable name and also you are ok with having different memory for non-const array, then this is the fastest way.

```
const uint16 arr[] = {1,2,3,4}
unint16 arr1[4];
memcpy(arr1,arr,sizeof(arr))
```

Comment: @rohank: first of all, do you know what `const` means? It means you should not modify it.

Comment: @rohank - we are not assigning anything to anything. we are simply copying the contents of const uint16 array to non-const uint16 array.

Comment: @Nawaz: Its the requirement in my project. I know its simply not acceptable but I need to cross this hurdle. So, please think about an work around.

Comment: @Manoj: Can memmove do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

const uint16_t  arr1[] = {1,2,3,4};
uint16_t* arr2 = const_cast<uint16_t*>(arr1);

for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    cout << "arr2[" << i << "] = " << arr2[i] << endl;
}
}
```

Note that I used pointer notation for arr2. If you do not understand why try changing
that line to

```
uint16_t arr2 = const_cast<uint16_t*>(arr1);
```

and see what the compiler tells you.

Comment: `const_cast` is not a good idea. what if `const uint16` is really permanently readonly in the program?